# How to use api/account/RegisterLogin in Asp.Net web api 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I want to use postman to text the external Google auth. 
I have not only the access token that Google provides but also this URL:

```
http://localhost:56099/api/Account/ExternalLogin?
provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A56099%2F
&state=pqUYyRJkopKQJhW4a5G6WKOxs1lpDlQSXs3iCRUMUyQ1
```

It gives `200 OK` response and shows the home page of my web site but still when using other methods like `account/userInfo` it gives unauthorize user.

What can I do?

Comment: If I have understood your problem correctly you have the access token and you want to access Account.userinfo which is only for authorized user and there you are getting unauthorize exception from postman  is it ?

Comment: yes i have the access token which i got from google in response. but still it shows unauthorized 

Also i wanted to ask... how external register works..

Comment: Pass it in Postman bearer token that all you need to do.Can you send me a screenshot how ar eyou accessing your API then accordingly I can answer.

Comment: https://github.com/KunalBurangi/react-react-auth   this is the link for whole project.... please have a look